# Php get records converbaet to two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to get record from database than convert to two dimensional array.

```
Example:

$data = array(
        1 => array ('Name', 'Surname','sex','address','web'),
        array('Schwarz', 'Oliver','M','KP','222.dddd'),
        array('Test', 'Peter','F','KK','wwww.fsadfs')
        );
```

How can format data from database as example above ?

Comment: `while($arr[] = $db->fetchRow())`? it's not exactly all that hard...

Comment: Dear Marc B, Can give me full coding with database?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3S7Nnp) is an example, using PDO and an in-memory SQLite database created inside the paste itself; having to create the database in-line makes the script a bit more verbose than is strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$i = 0;

foreach( $results as $result )
{
    $array[$i]['field1'] = $results['field1'];
    $array[$i]['field2'] = $results['field2'];

    $i++;
}
```

Depending on what library you're using to access the database it might be slightly different.

Comment: Hello, I dont understand what u mean?

Comment: Sorry, so for instance if you were using ADO, you could do `$results = $db->Execute($sql);`, and then you can iterate through `$results` as an associative array, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

here's your answer creating a function, return multiple arrays

```
public static function getRecords($query){  // Gets multiple records and    returns associative array
    $db = db::open();
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if(!$result){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $i=0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $recordset[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
            }
        }else{
            $recordset = false;
        }
    db::close($db);
    return ($recordset);
}
```

you just pass the query like

```
 $QUERY="select * FROM USERS";


AND CREATE class db to open the connection and also add function in this class and your function is ready 



    class db{
    public static function open(){ // opens the db connection. Specify different databases for local and live server and it will automatically select the correct one

       $servers = array('localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'warrior');
        if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $servers)){ //for localhost
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpwd = '';
            $dbname = 'database name';
            $dbserver = 'localhost';
        }
        $db = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$dbname);
        if ($db->connect_errno > 0){
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $db->connect_error;
          }
         return $db;
        }

    public static function close(&$db){
        $db->close();
    } //also add your Get_record function here
}
```

include file and test it 
thanks